# Fading between svg sprite background-position using background-check.js

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have a logo on my site which I need to simply fade between a light and dark version. The logo is on a moving slider, and so I am using the brilliant 'background-check' script (http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/) to determine which logo should be displayed. The script achieves this by applying a class to the logo, either 'background--light' or 'background--dark'. These classes determine solely the background-position of the svg sprite that si displaying the logo.

Currently, the change of classes means the logo 'moves' into place rather than fades, and none of the standard solutions I have found online such as adding a  for the state change will work as I am working with these classes. Can anyone point me in the right direction? A pure css solution is preferable, but am open to JQuery if required.

Thanks

**MARKUP**

```
<a href="#" class="logo check">Logo</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo.background--dark { background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat -120px 0; }
.logo.background--light { background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 0; }
```

Comment: You could go from light to dark via a [brightness filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) only one logo would be required then and you could animate it from dark to light, the browser would do all the interpolation calculations for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been solved, by adding a second logo element (not ideal but my best option in the situation). Hope this is a useful solution for others.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="logo check">Logo</a>
<a href="#" class="logo-invert">Logo</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    width: 85px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
}

.logo-invert {
    width: 85px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat -119px 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Background Check */
.logo.background--dark { opacity: 0; }
.logo.background--dark ~ .logo-invert { opacity: 1; }

.logo.background--light { opacity: 1; }
.logo.background--light ~ .logo-invert { opacity: 0; }
```